# How to keep counting across multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a multiple choice quiz. The questions are on different pages. Each right answer is worth 1 point. I need my js code to keep counting the points when going from one page to another.

Here is my code:

`page1.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <b>5+5=</b> <br><br>
      <form action="" id="questionform">
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" onclick="right()"><span>5</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" onclick="right()" id="rightanswer"><span>10</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" onclick="right()"><span>15</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" onclick="right()"><span>20</span><br>
      </form>
      <input type="submit" value="&#11013; Back" id="back" form="questionform" disabled>
      <input type="submit" value="Next &#10145;" id="next" form="questionform" formaction="page2.html">
      <script src="scorecode.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

`page2.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <b>5+20=</b> <br><br>
      <form action="" id="questionform">
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" onclick="right()"><span>10</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" onclick="right()"><span>15</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" onclick="right()"><span>20</span><br>
         <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" onclick="right()"  id="rightanswer"><span>25</span><br>
      </form>
      <input type="submit" value="&#11013; Back" id="back" form="questionform" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">
      <input type="submit" value="Next &#10145;" id="next" form="questionform" disabled>
      <script src="scorecode.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

`scorecode.js`

```
function right() {
    var total = 0;

    if (document.getElementById("rightanswer").checked) {
        total += 1;
        
        console.log(total);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    right();
});
```

I also have a problem with the button next. When I click on the button back then on the button next my checked answer disappears. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to store the score and choices somewhere. Can be in a backend server or browser storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localstorage to store that info.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To set the item use

```
localStorage.setItem('score', '1');
```

To get the item on the other page use

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('score');
```